# Use partial_fields in elasticsearch kibana query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to add the **partial_fields** directive to an elasticsearch query (generated from kibana's table widget).

Where exactly would I have to place this statement in the below ES query?

Already tried to add it right after the first "query" node which produces valid json but still doesn't exclude xmz_Data

```
    "partial_fields": {
    "partial1": {
        "exclude": "xmz_Data"
    }
},
```

ES Query

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match_all": {}
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {},
    "fragment_size": 2147483647,
    "pre_tags": [
      "@start-highlight@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@end-highlight@"
    ]
  },
  "size": 250,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the `partial_fields` directive anywhere in your query, I tested successfully with it both before and after the `query` node. However, your formatting for the excluded fields value is incorrect. Your exclude fields value needs to be an array. Try this instead...

```
  "partial_fields": {
     "partial1": {
        "exclude": ["xmz_Data"]
      }
  },
```